# Show existence of limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous periodical function with period $T>0$.
Show that:
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^Tf(ax)dx$$
exists and calculate this limit.

Comment: Substitute $u = ax$. Assume first that $a$ is an integer if that helps.

Comment: So the integral exsists since $f$ is continuous on an bounded interval

Comment: and is this limit equal to $T \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ generally doesn't exist (it exists if and only if $f$ is constant). Your first, now edited, comment was pretty much on target. There's a little work to do for the case when $a$ is not an integer.

Comment: $\int_0^Tf(x)dx=\int_0^{\frac{T}{a}}f(ax)dx$ for any $a<\infty$? hmm I dont think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $u = ax$, we obtain (for $a > 0$)

$$\int_0^T f(ax)\,dx = \frac{1}{a} \int_0^{aT} f(u)\,du.\tag{1}$$

If $a$ is an integer, then, since

$$\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T} f(u)\,du = \int_0^T f(x)\,dx$$

by the periodicity, $(1)$ becomes

$$\int_0^T f(ax)\,dx = \int_0^T f(x)\,dx.$$

So if the limit

$$\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_0^T f(ax)\,dx$$

exists at all, it must be $\int_0^T f(x)\,dx$. To see that the limit in fact exists, note that

$$\int_0^{aT} f(u)\,du = \int_0^{\lfloor a\rfloor T} f(u)\,du + \int_{\lfloor a\rfloor T}^{aT} f(u)\,du.$$

Comment: Beautifully written. Thank you sir!